# JQuery Change Image in a Group of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamic list with each row containing 6 image icons. Code Below...

```
<div class='list_body'>
<div class='lister1'>
    <img data-icon_no='1' data-job_id='"+job_id+"' data-icon_status='"+split_stats[0]+"' src='"+path+stat1+"' class='q1' />
    <img data-icon_no='2' data-job_id='"+job_id+"' data-icon_status='"+split_stats[1]+"' src='"+path+stat2+"' class='q1' />
    <img data-icon_no='3' data-job_id='"+job_id+"' data-icon_status='"+split_stats[2]+"' src='"+path+stat3+"' class='q1' />
    <img data-icon_no='4' data-job_id='"+job_id+"' data-icon_status='"+split_stats[3]+"' src='"+path+stat4+"' class='q1' />
    <img data-icon_no='5'  data-job_id='"+job_id+"' data-icon_status='"+split_stats[4]+"' src='"+path+stat5+"' class='q1' />
    <img data-icon_no='6' data-job_id='"+job_id+"' data-icon_status='"+split_stats[5]+"' src='"+path+stat6+"' class='q1' />
 </div>

 <div class='lister'>"+name+"</div>
    <div class='lister'>"+time+"</div>
    <div class='lister'><a href='javascript:void(0);'>View Appointment &amp; Actions</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Each icon has a status number and a different coloured icon image for each status. What I need to do is change the icon when the icon status value changes in the main database.

I am struggling to identify the icon with jquery selectors. I have tried:

```
$('.q1 img[data-job_id='+job_identifier+']').eq(0).attr('src', path+icon_url1);
```

(this was to hopefully change the first icon but did not work.)

I basically need to:
a: identify the row of icons based on the job-id
b: reset the icons with the correct img src
c: do this in the quickest way possible.

I hope this makes sense

Comment: I think your HTML mark up is wrong. You can't put JS variable like `job_id, split_stats, path+stat6` simply on the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Write it with double quote -

```
$('.q1 img[data-job_id="+job_identifier+"]').eq(0).attr('src', path+icon_url1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$('.list_body .lister1 img[data-job_id="+job_identifier+"]').attr('src', path+icon_url1);
```

you dont need `eq()` as you are filtering using id.

Comment: The code I put in is just one row - the job_identifier variable will be the same reference for all the icons - it will only alter per row. Thanks